# What is the fastest algorithm to solve $k$-path problem?

Tags: algorithms

**$k$-Path problem**

**The problem:** Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, does there exist a path of length $k$ in the graph?

The trivial algorithm to solve is in $O^*(n^k)$ time using dynamic programming. ($^*$ hides the polynomial factor.)

**Question:** What is the fastest algorithm for the $k$-Path problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FPT algorithms (ignoring the polynomial factors), there is a $2.851^k \cdot n^{O(1)}$ deterministic algorithm and a $1.66^k  \cdot n^{O(1)}$ randomized algorithm.

See [Table of FPT races](http://fpt.wikidot.com/fpt-races) for references.